# Nginx make basic auth behind ssh

Tags: nginx, centos

I am using `ssh` connection via nginx - i want to make authorization when user opens port 9201.

If i have sth like this:

```
stream {

       server {
          listen 9201;

          proxy_ssl off;

          location / {
            proxy_pass servername:9200;
            auth_basic "Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;
          } # end location
         } # end server
       } # end stream
```

i get an error

> nginx[8698]: nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here
>   in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:44

How can i make authorization here?
If i delete `auth*` lines this nginx works fine but without authorization.

Comment: There isn't a `location` directive in the `stream` module.

Comment: @RichardSmith cool - so how I can achieve my goal in a different way ? I think that i need `stream` cause of `ssh`